# Kafka Connect HDFS ignores flush.size in Confluent v4.0

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

With the migration to **Confluent v4.0**, the `flush.size` for **kafka-connect-hdfs** doesn't work for me anymore. It worked with **Confluent v3.x**.

This is the current configuration file:

```
name=my-job-name
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkConnector
tasks.max=1

topics=my-topic-name

hdfs.url=hdfs://my/path
hadoop.conf.dir=/etc/hadoop/conf/
flush.size=50000
#rotate.interval.ms=80000
```

When I start the job, it generates millions of small avro files in **HDFS**.

```
-rw-r--r--   ...     43.8 K 2018-01-29 13:26 /my/path/topics/my-topic-name/partition=5/my-topic-name+5+0000000000+0000000143.avro
-rw-r--r--   ...      3.7 K 2018-01-29 13:26 /my/path/topics/my-topic-name/partition=5/my-topic-name+5+0000000144+0000000149.avro
...
```

As you can tell from the offset, some of the files only contain 6 events. What do I miss? Why do I see this new behavior?

Comment: The schemas of two files are the same?

Comment: No, they are not. I made a mistake in the upstream kafka streams job. Thank you so much for pointing out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files will do this when the schemas of the messages change.

To inspect the schema messages (if using Avro), you can either get the schema ID of the message using its offset number in the file directly from Kafka, and hit the schema registry `GET /schemas/(schema-id)`.

Or download the files from HDFS, and use avro-tools `getschema` command.